# Выпадающий текст на html CSS

Tags: html, css

Можете помочь реализовать выпадающий текст как на картинке или статью, где это описывается, чтобы можно было изучить поподробнее. Заранее спасибо!)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте например [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) или на чистом css примеры [тут](https://codepen.io/raubaca/pen/PZzpVe)

Comment: Ищите "меню аккордеон". Есть варианты на чистом css/html

Comment: Всем больше спасибо, очень помогли!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
details>summary {
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='20px' height='20px' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg id='SVGRepo_bgCarrier' stroke-width='0'%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg id='SVGRepo_tracerCarrier' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg id='SVGRepo_iconCarrier'%3E%3Crect width='24' height='24' fill='white'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3Cpath d='M12 6V18' stroke='%23000000' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M6 12H18' stroke='%23000000' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

details>p {
  width: 250px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Accord</title>
</head>

<body>
  <details>
    <summary>Гарантии пассажира</summary>
    <p>Мы являемся официальным партнёром многих автовокзалов, перевозчиков и автобусных интеграторов России, стран СНГ и Европы. Распечатанный электронный билет равносилен купленному в кассе. Почитайте отзывы о нас</p>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Могу я забронировать билет на автобус?</summary>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Как вернуть купленный билет?</summary>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Можно ли вернуть купленный билет?</summary>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </details>
</body>

</html>
```

Вот так это можно реализовать